# Is it ok to erase from stl:map in concurrent with find

Tags: c++, stl

I wonder if is it ok to erase from stl:map in concurrent with find?
concurrent means - two threads that try both at the same time one to erase and one to call find.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrent"? One thread does `erase` while another calls `find`? That's not ok :)

Comment: Code example please. Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to protect read access to an STL container in a multithreading environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187583/do-i-need-to-protect-read-access-to-an-stl-container-in-a-multithreading-environ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course not. `stl::map` is based on an auto-balancing binary tree (red-black usually). `erase` may eventually cause a heavy tree rearrangement.

Answer (score 1):

It's not okay to call a `const` method and a non-`const` method on the same object at the same time and it's not okay to call 2 non-`const` methods at the same time. It is, however, okay to call 2 `const` methods at the same time. This applies to *all** `const` correct code, not just the standard library.

So, in your case no, it's not safe.

<sub>*Unless it's internally thread-safe, which is poor design. And nothing in the standard library is.</sub>