# do I need to protect access to different keys in a std::list (multi-threading) C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, list

I have 2 threads one inserting a pair ("key/value") into a list and the other one removing a pair from the same list.
Now I can guarantee that those threads will never be modifying the same "key/value" pair.

Is that thread safe of should I protect the list with mutexes?

thanks.

Comment: It all depends on your exact data structure, how the operations are implemented and the granularity of locking that you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to protect read access to an STL container in a multithreading environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187583/do-i-need-to-protect-read-access-to-an-stl-container-in-a-multithreading-environ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general any sort of modifications to any of the std containers should absolutely be protected.

You could consider using a pthread_rwlock, using a read lock for reading and a write lock for writing. The nice thing about rwlocks is that you can have multiple simultaneous readers, thus reducing locking contention. Or at the very least a pthread_mutex. (Assuming Linux, of course)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a linked list, right?
So imagine you start with `A->C->D`
You start removing `C`. It says "Ok, we need to redirect `A`'s `next` ptr.
But before it does, you start inserting `B`. This completes without being interrupted, and you end up with `A->B->C->D`. Then the removal carries on, changing `A` instead of `B`. You end up with `A->D` and `nothing->B->who knows?`.
So lock.

Comment: Not to mention the list attributes like the size.

Comment: That too, but before `c++11` there was no requirement for this to be available in constant time (i.e. stored), so it could be calculated every time by walking through the list. Of course, that just means you're slightly less likely to notice the problem, not that you're any better off. Or perhaps slightly more likely if you call `size()` part way through without locking? Who knows, either way it's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like mutex is required... there is list management that goes along with insert and erase functions and you don't want that colliding.  if you knew the exact implementation details of the list management you might be able to write some specialty code such that a mutex wasn't required, but it's your easiest/safest route.  from a performance perspective, you might want to lock just the list access regions... i.e. operate->lock->insert->unlock in the one thread, and lock->remove->unlock->operate in the other thread.