# Is the C++ standard library thread safe?

Tags: c++, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to protect read access to an STL container in a multithreading environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187583/do-i-need-to-protect-read-access-to-an-stl-container-in-a-multithreading-environ)

I am using the C++ standard library which comes with (Linux) GCC or (Windows) VC.

Can anyone please say clearly whether or not this library is thread safe?

Comment: It isn't. Unless stated otherwise. You can find all of that in documentation like http://cppreference.com or the [standard specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Comment: As often the answer is "that depends". For the containers of the C++ standard library you will find helpful information about "thread safety" here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Answer (score 3):

"Thread safe" is not a clearly-defined boolean property of a library. Some things can be done concurrently and others cannot.

Almost certainly if you were to ask a more detailed question specifying what it is you want to do, the answer would be "no, it is not thread-safe". But only almost.

If by "thread-safe" you mean something like the difference between `Vector` and `ArrayList` in Java, then C++ standard containers are non-thread-safe.